# How to tell if I have a firewall installed on my VM

Tags: 12.04, firewall, virtualization

I inherited a college VM I am trying to setup to accept remote connections to its MySQL DB from my local phpMyAdmin

I am going through some [SO Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801573/how-to-access-remote-server-with-local-phpmyadmin-client/23270907#23270907) and tutorials ([this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-distribution-name-version-number/)/[this](https://degreesofzero.com/article/manage-remote-mysql-servers-with-local-phpmyadmin.html)) on setting this up all of which mention that I need to make sure my firewall is configured properly to allow connections though

I am continuously learning Linux/VMs and have little or no experience with Firewalls

Is there a command that will tell me if there is any Firewall already installed on my VM?

Thanks

```
name@vm-18:/$ uname -a
Linux kdeg-vm-18 3.2.0-37-virtual #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 15:48:03 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


name@vm-18:/$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.5 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
```

Comment: We need more info on your setup.  When you say "Local phpMyAdmin" what do you mean by local, local to the VM or to your host computer?  Also, what networking interface is the VM using?  NAT?  Bridged?  etc.

Comment: Local, as in from my desktop

Comment: I have no idea about the Networking interface, ill try look into it

Comment: Most of the tme, low level firewalling stuff is made with **iptables. So `iptables -L` shoudl be enough to know if there is a firewall running. Not making one. Just checking

Comment: @solsTiCe Thanks for the info. I would be happy to accept if you write it up as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, whatever the firewall tool you use, the low level firewalling stuff is made with **iptables**.

So with `iptables -L`, you should be able to tell if there is a firewall running. Not making one. Just checking.

Unless you use `nftables`, but this could hardly be the case.